# Histograms with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` containing counts of various ages :

```
age    count
0      39
1      27
2      27
3      26
```

I'm trying to plot a histogram of these counts. This is easy enough using the default `hist` function, done by `hist(rep.int(df$age, times = df$count))`.

How can this be done in ggplot? I'm fairly new to R so sorry if I've missed something basic.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Nathan I got it working. Just in case anyone stumbles on this here's how I got it to work (there's probably a slicker way).

```
# Make a dataframe of counts
age <- as.data.frame(rep.int(df$age, times = df$count))
# Note : Column is called rep.int(df$age, times = df$count)

ggplot(data = age, aes(x = rep.int(df$age, times = df$count))) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = .5)
```

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried already? If you're not familiar with it yet, the [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/) might give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R can be confusing, to do what you're looking for you can visit
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf

I use this in my advanced data analysis class.

Also, specifically if you're working in the console then

> library (ggplot2)
>
> b <- ggplot()
>
> b + geom_bar(data=df,aes(x="age")

I'm assuming that df is your dataframe name, as shown in the upper right corner of R or R studio, and that age is the variable that you want to plot.

Let me know, I've got R installed and can help out.

Comment: [markdown](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) this is the same kind of cheetsheat for markdown, hope this helps you in the future!

Comment: These cheat sheets really helped! I got it all working. Thanks!